# DB2 iSeries - not able to access table from stored proc

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

I am accessing DB2 iSeries version 6.3 using JDBC driver. The call to a stored procedure fails with the following error:

```
[SQL0204] GENHST in TSTUSR type *FILE not found.
```

The connection string is:

```
jdbc:as400://db2.abc.com/DBName;naming=system;libraries=*LIBL;block size=512;lob threshold=0;package library=QGPL;prompt=false;translate binary=true;remarks=system;cursor hold=false;
```

When I connect using Squirrel client with the same user and same connection string as I used for JDBC connection, I am able to view data in GENHST table. The stored proc is referring to GENHST table without specifying a schema name.

Please help with any ideas. What could be going wrong?

### EDIT:

The issue is fixed if I remove the database name from the connection string and add the schema that contains the stored proc to the connection string.

```
jdbc:as400://db2.abc.com/;naming=system;libraries=*LIBL,PROC_SHEMA;block size=512;lob threshold=0;package library=QGPL;prompt=false;translate binary=true;remarks=system;cursor hold=false;
```

I do not really understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described in the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzahh/jdbcliblistproperty.htm) line *4. Default SQL schema specified on URL and "libraries" property specified*

> Default SQL schema is what is specified in the URL. Library list is not searched to resolve unqualified name in SQL statements.

Comment: My doubt is - if I am able to query the table from Squirrel sql client why is that the stored proc is not able to find it.

Comment: @pawindergupta the SP is not able to find it because the way the places (default schema or library list) where the table is searched is defined as procedure's creation time, not runtime